# Handlebars and async call

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I use this helper to check wether an image exists or not:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('checkLogo', function(url) {

      UrlExists(url, function(status){
      if(status === 200){    
       return new Handlebars.SafeString(url)
      }
      else if(status === 404){        
        console.log('no logo found');
      }
});
});


function UrlExists(url, cb){
    $.ajax({
        url:      url,
        dataType: 'text',
        type:     'GET',
        complete:  function(xhr){
            if(typeof cb === 'function')
               cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
        }
    });
}
```

I call it (with a url as arg) in my template like this:

```
<img src="{{checkLogo logo}}"/>
```

Im expecting `{{checkLogo logo}}` to be replaced by the url but nothing gets returned. Is it maybe beacuse of the async action and because of this it has to be handled differently?

Thank you

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Handlebars does _not_ support asynchronous helpers at all. See also [this issue](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/717).

Comment: Ok thank you, guess I´ll have to find another way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though Handlebars doesn't support asynchronous helpers you can still use helpers to achieve this. Create some unique html with a helper and detect it being added to the DOM using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). Then you can get a hold of the added `img` element and modify it however you like.

A much simpler and more efficient solution would be to use the `onerror` attribute of `img` element to trigger some callback. [Here's an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmxxjwzu/1/). [Another fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmxxjwzu/3/) that uses a handlebars template.

If you want to explore the Handlebars + MutationObserver way, I've created a helper that you can use or adapt. It's available at https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars and demonstrated in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suurxkot/).

[watch.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/watch.js) defines a function `forHtml(html, callback)` which triggers a callback when the given html is encountered in the DOM. It modifies the html to temporarily have a class that makes it unique.

[helpers.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/helpers.js) defines the helper `renderer` and the function `createRenderer(getHtmlContentFn)` which wraps your function into a renderer and that can be passed in to a template and used as an argument for the helper.

Comment: Thank you very much, making use of onerror would have been great. However it does not seem to work when the img-element is inside of a handlebars-template? Im gonna look into watch.js and helpers.js!

Comment: I'm positive you can get onerror to work with handlebars as well. Maybe you could create a fiddle that I can take a look at?

Comment: Great! Give me a couple of minutes to try to set it up :)

Comment: I have some trouble rendering the template in the fiddle, can you spot it maybe?
http://jsfiddle.net/hmxxjwzu/2/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hmxxjwzu/3/ I fixed a syntax error in the second onclick attribute and added jquery and current version of handlebars as external resources. And I added the onerror attribute to the img and my own callback for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted this as well, found a way:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelperFunctionName', function (item) {
    var element_id = 'temp-prefix-' + item, item_html = false;
    // make async call here:
    SlowAsyncCallbackPromiseThing(item, function(item_object){
        item_html = Handlebars.templates.item(item_object);
        $('span#' + element_id).replaceWith(item_html);
    });
    if(item_html){//cache resolved immediately
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(item_html);
    }
    // If the cache is barren, provide a loading span to be replaced later.
    return new Handlebars.SafeString('<span id="' + element_id + '">Loading..</span>');
});
```

Now, when you load it, the inner jQuery simply replaces the temporary element when it eventually resolves.. not the best, but it's fast and works with Handlebars. I use a lot of localStorage caching, so some of the Promises resolve instantly. Absolute headache to troubleshoot till I figured out why it wasn't working always.

To adapt that to a property of an element.. wouldn't be that hard, but you'd need some way of identifying the element