# Creating a function to return the value obtained from a webserver

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm trying to create a function to use as a helper for template expander to ask questions from the user and put the answer in the template. I have a local service that takes HTML for displaying the question and returning the answer. But, I keep getting only the promise and not the final answer. The function will be using in a template expander, so I need the actual data returned.

This is the code I've been working on:

```
const axios = require('axios');

async function getAnswer( Question, Default ) {
  var ans = '';
  try {
    var obj = {
      html: "<label>" + Question + "</label><input id='name' type='text' value='" + Default + "' autofocus ></input><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"globalThis.sendBack()\">Okay</button> <script>globalThis.sendBack = function() { globalThis.BBData.dialogStore.dialogResult = document.getElementById('name').value; globalThis.BBData.dialogStore.callBack(); } </script>",
      width: 170,
      height: 50,
      x: 50,
      y: 100
    }

    const res = await axios({
      url: 'http://localhost:9697/api/dialog',
      method: 'put',
      data: obj
    });
    ans = res.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
  return(ans);
}

console.log(getAnswer("What is your name?",""));
```

I expect the function to just return the data, but I get a promise.

Answer (score 0):

The result of an `async` function *always* is a promise.

Try running `(async function () { return 3; })()` - you'll get a promise for the number 3, even though 3, like `res` in your function, is not a promise itself.

```
async function getAnswer( Question, Default ) {
  // ...
  const res = await axios( /* ... */ );

  return res.data;  
}
```

So either you use `await` all the way - which means you need to wrap your calling code in an async function:

```
async function caller () {
  console.log(await getAnswer("What is your name?",""));
}
caller();
```

or you handle the Promise explicitly:

```
getAnswer("What is your name?","").then(answer => console.log(answer));
```

---

Your function returns a promise, sends the axios request (which also returns a promise), waits for the response, unwraps the axios promise and finally resolves the promise it gave initially with the axios result value.

Personally, I find it more straightforward (and less busy to look at) to use promise semantics here. It also cuts out one level of promise wrapping and unwrapping:

```
function getAnswer(Question, Default) {
  return axios({
    url: 'http://localhost:9697/api/dialog',
    method: 'put',
    data: {
      html: "<label>" + Question + "</label><input id='name' type='text' value='" + Default + "' autofocus ></input><button type=\"button\" onclick=\"globalThis.sendBack()\">Okay</button> <script>globalThis.sendBack = function() { globalThis.BBData.dialogStore.dialogResult = document.getElementById('name').value; globalThis.BBData.dialogStore.callBack(); } </script>",
      width: 170,
      height: 50,
      x: 50,
      y: 100
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    return '';
  });
}
```

Comment: But, I still can’t use any of these in a helper function for a template engine. I need a way to query a web site and just return the answer.

Comment: You cannot "just return the answer." You must get over this notion. An asynchronous function is an asynchronous function stays an asynchronous function. Anything you can do is register a callback and carry out the work you intend to do in the callback. Promises and async/await are just syntactic sugar for this basic fact, they can't save you from it. I've linked to a workaround for your specific situation in the comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

you have used the promise in this situation when want to call this function you must add async where are you want to use it after the value should be value used then keyword

```
async function whenWantused() {
  await getAnswer("What is your name?","");
}
```

or used this syantic

```
getAnswer("what take paramater" ).then(res=>//what want to do heare)
```

Comment: That will not work because I need to return it to the function that calls. I’m using the function `getAnswer()` inside of a mustache helper function. Therefore, using the callback in the then statement doesn’t work.

Comment: I explain the way to how to write not the solution try to use this syntax

Comment: @Richard These kinds of details belong into the question. That being said, Handlebars does not support asynchronous helpers, and there is no way to make an asynchronous call synchronous, if that's what you thought that `await` would do. It doesn't. There are ways to work around this limitation in Handlebars, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34905864/handlebars-and-async-call)

Comment: Thanks @Tomalak. Nodejs doesn't do sync tcp requests is the conclusion I've come to as well. To get around this, I need to use a child process to run something like wget to get the information. I'm using a tcp interface to get a command line template expansion to the clipboard, so using a temp element and replacing it will not work. I did find a library to work, sync-request, but the library doesn't seem to work with NW.js.

Comment: No, you don't need to run a child process and wget. Have you tried the method I linked to?

Comment: As a method of last resort you can use [synchronous XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request) in the browser, but I *really* recommend against that approach. Personally I would go out of my way to avoid it, from trying things like [async-helpers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-helpers) all the way to up to using a different templating engine.

Comment: @Tomalak I’m not in a browser. I’m running a template expander inside of NW.js that is sending the expanded template to the user request in another tcp transaction. No DOM at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. NW.js *contains* Chromium and therefore it has a DOM. You need to make a [mcve].