# Handlebars.registerHelper returns nothing

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, helper, express-handlebars

I created a helper in Handlebars that does two searches in the database and tells me the name of the user's profile photo. However, this helper is not returning anything, and I did it in the same way as two other helpers in the code.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("userPhoto", (author, options) => {
    User.findOne({username: author}).then(user => {
        Profile.findOne({userId: user._id}).lean().then(profile => {
            const photoURL = `/img/user/${profile.photo}`;
            return options.fn({photoURL: photoURL});
        }).catch(error => {
            devErrors.throw.db(error);
            return options.inverse(this);
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        devErrors.throw.db(error);
        return options.inverse(this);
    });
});
```

And here's my Handlebars code:

```
<img id="img" src="{{#userPhoto author}}{{photoURL}}{{/userPhoto}}" style="border: hidden 1px; border-radius: 50%;" alt="Foto de Perfil" width="50" height="50">
```

Comment: What does your helper return?

Comment: That's the point - it returns nothing. Well, when I tried to log the return value in the console, it returned undefined, but in the HTML it only displays (unknown).

Comment: I apologize if I was being cryptic. What I was trying to point out to you is that your helper _does not_ have a return statement, so it will return `undefined`. However, even if you were to add a `return` before `User.findOne` you will still have a problem because your helper will return a Promise, but Handlebars requires simple values, like strings or numbers, and won't know what to do with a Promise. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/34905864/3397771

Comment: I also apologize, because I believe I expressed myself badly. Your comment was good enough for me to understand the problem and be able to resolve it on my own, so I think you should post it as an answer, so that I can mark the question as resolved and give you an upvote.

Comment: Thank you. I am happy to help, but I don't think my contribution is sufficient to be an answer. I encourage you to post the solution you arrived at. Have a good day!